# Reuse methods in a Rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-generate

I'm writing a series of Rails generators that will share several of the same methods. I would like to abstract these methods into a module or class of their own to be reused (but not automatically fired) within each of my generators.

My latest attempt was to autoload a helper file and later include it:

**lib/my_gem/engine.rb**

```
module MyGem
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/helpers/**"]
  end
end
```

**lib/helpers/generators_helper.rb**

```
module MyGem
  module GeneratorsHelper
    def some_method
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

**lib/generators/my_gem/my_generator.rb**

```
# ...
include MyGem::GeneratorsHelper
# ...
```

But I'll see something like `Error: uninitialized constant MyGem::GeneratorsHelper.`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by manually requiring the file and then including the module. It's a little ugly, but keeps me from duplicating helper methods:

**lib/my_gem/generators/my_generator.rb**

```
require "#{Gem::Specification.find_by_name("my_gem").gem_dir}/lib/helpers/generators_helper.rb"
include MyGem::GeneratorsHelper
```